# Limitations of Autowiring

Tags: spring

I read a limitation of Spring:

"Explicit dependencies in property and constructor-arg settings always override autowiring. You cannot autowire so-called simple properties such as primitives, Strings, and Classes (and arrays of such simple properties). This limitation is by-design."

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that if you have this:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private MyOtherClass myOtherClass;

    public MyClass(final MyOtherClass myOtherClass) {
        this.myOtherClass = myOtherClass;
    }
}

<bean class="com.something.MyClass">
    <constructor-arg name="myOtherClass" class="com.something.MyOtherClass" />
</bean>
```

The value of the `myOtherClass` variable will be that set through the constructor, not the one autowired. Same goes if `myOtherClass` is set through a `setter` and the `<property>`-element.

Also, you can't do this:

```
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    private String someString;

    @Autowired
    private int someInt;
}
```

.. which makes sense, in these cases use `@Value` instead.

In practice this does not have that many consequences, usually your beans will be `singletons`, and whether it is injected through `@Autowired` or through constructor/property, as long as it's the same bean it makes no difference.

Comment: What does it means? `and Classes` what classes?

Comment: what is meaning of _override autowiring_ in **...settings always override autowiring...**  ?

Answer (score 0):

There are three weaknesses of autowiring :

1. **Overriding:** You can still specify dependencies using `<constructor-arg>` and `<property>` settings which will always override `@Autowired`.
2. **Primitive data types:** Autowiring can't be used to inject primitive and string values. It works with reference only.
3. **Confusing nature:** `@Autowired` is less exact than explicit wiring, so if possible prefer using explicit wiring.